# VNC Server Password not changing on port 5900

Tags: passwords, vnc, vncserver, tightvnc, metasploit

I'm trying to fix the [VNC Server 'password' Password](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/61708) vulnerability of [Metasploitable 2](https://docs.rapid7.com/metasploit/metasploitable-2/). I have changed the vncserver password using `vncpasswd` and it works fine for all the ports but `5900`. After changing the password I can still connect to `ip:5900` with the password `password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting via VNC using the `5900` port automatically uses the `root` user, so in order for the password change to work it has to be done with `root`.

1. `sudo su`
2. `[sudo] password for <user>:`
3. `root@yourpc: vncpasswd`